# Adding Numbers to first column in a Table

Tags: jquery

I am trying and adding numbers to a table in the first col

```
var newCol = "<td></td>";
$('#target tbody tr').append(newCol);
$('#target tbody tr').each(function (idx) {
    $(this).children(":eq(0)").html(idx);
});
```

But I am not sure why isn't the code working? http://jsfiddle.net/9RHH2/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target is already the tbody, change selector and use:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9RHH2/2/)

```
var newCol = "<td class='rownum'></td>";
$('#target tr').each(function (i) {
    $(this).prepend($(newCol).text(i + 1))
});
```

Or using CSS only:

```
table {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

[DEMO CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/9RHH2/3/)

Comment: Thank you. If there are headers, how to handle that? http://jsfiddle.net/9RHH2/4/. I want that a separate <th> be also created for the number column

Comment: Oh yes it does..mind putting some comments back there to help me undersand.